# If $A$ and $B$ are ideals of a ring $R$. Then $A+B$ is an ideal of $R$ generated by $A \cup B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have proved that $A+B$ is an ideal of $R$. But I'm not able to prove that it is generated by $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Ideal $J$ is by definition the ideal generated by $A\cup B$ iff

- $J$ is an ideal.
- $A\cup B\subseteq J$.
- If $I$ is an ideal with $A\cup B\subseteq I$ then $J\subseteq I$.

Now try to prove $J=A+B$ has these properties in the special case where $A,B$ are ideals .

(You said that you already proved yourself that it has the first property)

Comment: Thanks for the help! And yes I've proved the first property but now dont know how to prove the other two.

Comment: Do you agree that $A\subseteq A+B$ and $B\subseteq A+B$? That gives the second property.

Comment: Yes!! Okay and what about the third one?

Comment: It remains to prove that $A,B\subseteq I$ implies that $A+B\subseteq I$ for any ideal $I$. Well, elements of $A+B$ have the shape $a+b$ with $a\in A\subseteq I$ and $b\in B\subseteq I$. Then it follows that $a+b\in I$ since ideal $I$ is closed under addition.

Comment: It's okay.I got it.Thanks a lot for clearing my doubts!

Comment: If this answer is enough for you then you can accept it.